# Is 'faire sentir' used in french?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, ordre-des-mots, pronoms-réfléchis

When saying 'something makes me/you/etc. feel something' is it possible to use the 'faire sentir' construction.

i.e. le film me faire sentir triste

i.e. quand je lui parle, elle me faire sentir comme si je ne suis pas aussi intelligent qu'elle.

I have read differing things about this phrase such as whether or not to use 'faire sentir' or 'faire se sentir' or if a phrase such as 'elle me faire me sentir heureux' is viable or not. For example, on WordReference, the translation for 'make someone feel at home' is 'faire se sentir chez soi.' The example given beneath, however, is "Un repas chaud me fait sentir chez moi quand je rentre du travail" which seems to be missing the reflexive pronoun for 'sentir' and this has confused me more. I understand that 'donner l'impression/envie' can also be used as an alternative but am unsure if certain context cues, if any, determines usage or if 'faire (se) sentir' can work most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Ce qui suit vaudrait aussi pour d'autres verbes que *faire*. (laisser, emmener, envoyer...)

1/ Si c'est à toi que cela *fait* quelque chose alors... forcément, comme pour tout autre verbe, le pronom doit le précéder. => Elle **TE** fait !

2/ Maintenant, tout va dépendre de ce qui suit.

- Si ce qui suit est un verbe **essentiellement pronominal** à l'infinitif alors... forcément... pas de lézard, il faut évidemment garder son pronom :

Elle **te** fait **t**'abstenir, Elle **te** fait **te** gargariser, Elle **te** fait **te** blottir...

- Si ce qui suit est juste pronominal ou utilisé pronominalement alors la construction ci-dessus reste possible, mais on **peut** faire l'omission du pronom :

C'est le cas de sentir, d'où on dira :

- Elle **te** fait **te** sentir moins intelligent,

Mais aussi bien :

- Elle **te** fait sentir moins intelligent,

Comment: Merci. Alors, si je veux dire 'I don't mean to make you feel pressured' les phrases, 'je n'ai pas l'intention de vous faire vous sentir pressé' ou 'je n'ai pas l'intention de vous faire sentir pressé' peut marcher bien tous les deux en francais?

Comment: @Montéedelait : Merci ++

Comment: @ArmaanKapila : Absolument. Enfin, grammaticalement je veux dire. Par ce que sinon, pour ce qui est de dire ce que tu veux dire maintenant, j'omettrais la tournure *faire sentir* : *Je n'ai pas l'intention **de vous presser*** que je trouve ainsi par moins lourde.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** It is not possible if the form is to be taken strictly as written; "feel sth" in the phrase given is "se sentir".

It's probably a good idea to situate the construction better first; the verb "faire" in this type of usage (i.e. that in the English sentence) must be constructed with two  elements of which the second is optional according to the verb used; the construction is  "**faire** *forme verbale (qqu/qqc)*" if "qqu/qqc)" is a *noun*.

If, in an evident way, the verb (forme verbale) can have for subject only human beings, or if it is so in a given context, then the second part (qqu), which is in plain sentences a subject to those verbs, can be either used or omitted. Here are some of those verbs:

> parler, réfléchir, rire, pleurer, démanger, comprendre, frissonner, apprendre,…
>    vivre, cracher, souffler, souffrir,…

exemples

> Le vent fait **tourner** *la girouette*. _ Le ressort fait **monter** *le poids*.
>   Les clowns font **rire**. _ Les clowns font **rire** les enfants. _ L'argent fait **vivre**. _ L'argent fait **vivre** ceux qui en ont.

There is sometimes the possibility of an inversion, particularly in cases of complex verbal forms.

> La fin de l'été fait s'en aller les hirondelles. _ (*also*) La fin de l'été fait les hirondelles s'en aller.

**2.** When "(qqu/qqc)" is a pronoun or when the verbal form is complex, the construction is "**faire** (qqu/qqc) *forme verbale*".

exemples

> Les huissiers *vous* font **payer**. _ Une seule torpille *nous* fera **couler**.
>   Ça fait **réfléchir**. _ Ça *nous* fait **réfléchir**. _ Les fortes chaleurs  font **languir**. _Les fortes chaleurs *te* font **languir**.

After the preceding little sketch of the grammatical context, things should become simpler. The verbal form that renders "to feel sth" is "se sentir"  and **not "sentir"**, it is the pronominal form. As "(qqu/qqc)" is a pronoun (me), the construction is the second one.

> "Le film me fait me sentir triste".
>   Quand je lui parle elle me fait me sentir comme si je ne n'était<sup>1</sup> pas aussi intelligent qu'elle.

**3.** The last point mentioned is quite interesting; it is clear that both the too close  morphological similarity of the two forms and the too close proximity of the pronouns wreak havoc in the average speaker's mind and that they are responsible for the mess that you can witness. There is one certitude: disregarding the strict structure of those forms and simplifying one of them makes for a blurring of the sense of discrimination, for a weakening of the habit of identification; on top of that it is certain that ambiguities too difficult to prevent will occur, if not in the case of using an adjective, as the constructions of the type "sentir triste" are meaningless, certainly in the case of using a noun. Consider the following.

- Elle était arrivée à te faire sentir du désarroi.

If the simplification is accepted, which is the assertion being made, " « te » éprouve « son propre désarroi »" or "« te » éprouve « le désarroi de « elle »»" (de « elle » ou qqu d'autre)?

This state of affairs indicates to me  that sound, as simple as possible habits and habit forming are necessary; the key to such requirements does not rest with polyvalent but one-to-one  correspondences.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>correction de « comme si je ne suis pas aussi » après lecture de [BBBreiz](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32270/17649)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The post given by aCOSwl is quite right about the "*verbes pronominaux*". In your examples, you couldn't say `elle me faire sentir`, but you should have said `elle me fait me sentir`. Please notice `elle me fait` instead of `elle me faire`, just like in English you say `she makes me feel` and not `she make me feel`

Moreover, in that sentence, you shouldn't have written `comme si je ne suis pas`, because "comme si" needs a conditional tense, so you should have said `comme si je n'étais pas` .

But the main problem is that the correct form `elle me fait me sentir`, though grammatically correct, is heavy end inelegant. In fact, a French speaker would use another expression, like `donner l'impresion`.

So your sentence:

> le film me faire sentir triste

would become:

> Le film m'a rendu triste

or

> le film m'a laissé une impression de tristesse

and

> Quand je lui parle, elle me faire sentir comme si je ne suis pas aussi
>   intelligent qu'elle

would become;

> Quand je lui parle, elle me donne l'impresion de ne pas être aussi
>   intelligent qu'elle

Comment: "*is heavy and inelegant*"... Hmmm... ceci est un jugement de valeur que je ne partage pas nécessairement et que ne me semblent pas non plus partager une bonne quantité d'auteurs pas particulièrement connus pour l'inélégance de leur style...

Comment: Je maintiens que "elle me fait me sentir" est particulièrement inélégant. Citez-moi un auteur réputé utilisant cette forme et je m'inclinerai. Peut-être trouverez-vous un pompier du XIXe, et encore...

Comment: Hmmm... Aragon et Elsa Triolet ça compte ou ça fait trop pompier du XIXè ? (Pardon à mes contemporains, je souhaitais nous éviter une mise en cause de *réputation*.)

Comment: Ha! J'avais oublié dans le commentaire précédent que... je ne cherchais en aucun cas à vous faire vous incliner... ;-) chacun devant absolument rester libre de son incli..naison.